# Weebly won't upload my CSS

Tags: html, css, upload

When I try to upload a CSS template that I made for Weebly, it says "Error: File Could Not Be Uploaded". I have tried and tried again and nothing.

Comment: Contact Weebly support, then... what can we do?

Comment: I was hoping that maybe someone had a solution.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kinds of questions are a good fit for SO. All I can tell you is that the contents of your CSS is not causing the problem (unless the file's too big, maybe).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to contact support. Weebly doesn't support more than one CSS file. I'm assuming you're trying to upload it into the "Files" section of the editor. You'll have to copy your styles and paste them to the end of the "main-style.css" file.

Even if you're importing a theme, it still has to have that same, and lonely css file. It's a good standard as it forces designers to not upload heaps of files slowing down the load time due to multiple server requests.!

[Screenshot with instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd61L.png)